# $\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}|\hat f(n)|<\infty$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with $f'$ integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}|\hat f(n)|<\infty$

I know $(in)\hat f(n)=\hat {f'}(n)$, but it seems to tell nothing about the infinite sum, also I know $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}|\hat f(n)|^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f(x)|^2dx<\infty$ by Parseval's identity, but it has a extra square and I have no idea how to remove that square to get the desired results. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: You may want to look up the [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: but there is a absolute sign for $\hat f(n)$........how can I know the fourier transform of $|f|$ ?

Comment: Have you look at the fourier series of $f(x) = |x|$?.

Comment: You could try out $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(n)| = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg|\frac{\widehat{f'}(n)}{n}\bigg|.$$
In a similar way one can show that $\hat f \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$ if $f$ has a continuous second derivative since $$|\hat{f}(n)|=\bigg|\frac{\widehat{f''}(n)}{n^2} \bigg|\leq \frac{1}{n^2} ||f''||_{L^1}.$$
But the missing square of $n$ in your case is quite problematic.

Comment: I have considered this approach, but the problem doesn't say that $f$ is twice differentiable..........

Comment: @JackyChong I will get $|\hat f(n)| = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}cos((2n-1)\hat f(n))$
But I still need to sum them up.......

Comment: @Longitude: The Wikipedia article says that the series converges **absolutely**.